# EditText.setError for a not focusable view

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to show error for a not focusable EditText. But I can not see the message. Only red icon. Somebody says I need to request the focus manually. This is how I did:

```
mStartDateEditText.requestFocus();
mStartDateEditText.setError("Message");
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: but if it is not focusable how it will have error??

Comment: I've got a sepcial OnClickListener for EditText. Date picker dialog appears and picked date is set to EditText.

Comment: Simply use a textview in this case instead of editext

Comment: Ok I did. Also I add style="@android:style/Widget.EditText" to textView. But now my listener is not working. StackOverflow says I should make my view unfocusable.

Comment: for a simple solution make a hidden field for error below textview and make it visible whenever there is any error

Answer (score -1):

In my case is similar i used a `TextWatcher` , e.g.:

```
   username.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.length()==0){
                    username.requestFocus();
                    username.setError("Please enter your username.");
                }else{
                    username.setError(null);
                }
            }
        });
```